# Bootstrap navbar image size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg, navbar

I've started setting up my own website using bootstrap/css, etc and i've got the basic look/layout that I'm trying to achieve though I am wanting to replace the navbar brand with an image, something that I am able to do; but with limited success...

I am struggling with getting a much larger .svg image to scale properly to sit in the correct space - it currently blows the site out of all proportion. Prior to this I had a .jpg that looked fine on desktop, but sucked quite badly on mobile.

Here's the code I've got for the navbar & image:

```
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Chris MacDonald Visualisation</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
            <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

            <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" Role = "Navigation">
                <div class = "container">

                        <div class = "logocontainer pull-left">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                                <img src="img/motif.svg">
                            </a>
                        </div>


                    <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>



                    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li class = "active"><a href = "#">Works</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "about.html">About Me</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>                
            </div>
```

I hope this makes sense to you guys, it's my first foray into coding a site and not using some kind of application to make it for me. If you want to see how this problem looks; www.cmvisual.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't close your `logocontainer` div. Setting a `width` to the img could work. `.navbar-brand img { width: 123px; }`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, have adjusted it.

I still can't figure out why it won't work. I've tried adding so many different things into both the html and/or css to control the width/height but I just can't get it to resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using SVG and according to the w3school "An SVG image begins with an  element" else in a normal way Your image is too big you have to use the short image else you can put the css for width. But best is you should use the small image

Comment: Surely using a large SVG provides better resolution on retina displays, etc? The actual file size of the SVG is really small too, so I don't think bandwidth should be affected too much.

What does it mean by "begins with an element"?

Comment: like when we use svg image than we use to put it in <svg></svg>

Check this http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp